# Can (and should) I use Lerna without publishing to NPM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lerna

I have an app and I have a storybook. They both live inside the same app at the moment. I have just installed Lerna and played around so I can treat them both as 2 separate packages.

Both packages will be dockerised and when I build one, it should not do anything with the other

my structure so far:

```
app/
  package.json
  lerna.json
  makefile
  packages/
    my-app/
      all-relevant-packages-for-my-app
      package.json
    storybook/
      all-relevant-packages-for-storybook
      package.json
```

I don't want to publish anything to NPM. I simply want to use these packages separately but I would like to import `app` components into the `storybook`

is Lerna the correct thing to use here?

when I run say `docker build my-app` it should go inside the `my-app` repo and then build the docker image etc, run tests and deploy my app to S3 (this is all set up already) but now I've moved it all I'm wondering if Lerna is the correct tool as I see lots about publishing to NPM

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use Lerna in your case. I'd recommend you to use Yarn Workspaces. Let's install `yarn` and then add

```
"workspaces": [
   "packages/*"
 ],
```

section to your main package.json file. From now on, yarn will be handling packages dependencies.

In your case - please enter the `package.json` of `my-app` and change its name to e.g. `@app/my-app'. Check the version of my-app in package.json (I will assume its 1.0.0 for now).

Do the same with `storybook` changing its name to e.g. `@app/storybook`. Then you can add a dependency in storybook's package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@app/my-app": "1.0.0"
   ...
}
```

Go back to the root directory `app` and run `yarn` command. It will resolve all dependencies for all packages. Now you can use my-app inside storybook without the necessity of using Lerna.